# How to Remove Leading "0" in a string in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, substring

I am looking to remove the leading zeros in a string.

**Below are my current results:**

```
Department
026P-PLUMBING
0021-LUMBER
029B-KITCHEN AND BATH
025H-HARDWARE (25H)
0022-BUILDING MATERIALS
```

**Below are my Desired Results:**

```
Department
26P-PLUMBING
21-LUMBER
29B-KITCHEN AND BATH
25H-HARDWARE (25H)
22-BUILDING MATERIALS
```

Comment: ```REGEXP_REPLACE```, should work.  ```regexp_replace(col_name,r'^0+','')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LTRIM(Department, '0')`  as in below example

```
select trim(Department, '0')
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]